# Revolver Question

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

The revolver text doesn't say that the target needs a Speed roll in order to use the revolver on a monster. If a monster doesn't have a speed trait, how does it defend?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot attack a monster who doesn't have speed with the Revolver. The general attack rules state:

> You can't use a trait to attack an opponent who doesn't have that trait.